# Regex non-greedy match

Tags: c#, regex

If I have the following simplified string:

```
        string331-itemR-icon253,string131-itemA-icon453,
string12131-itemB-icon4535,string22-itemC-icon443
```

How do I get the following only using only regex?

```
string12131-itemB-icon4535,
```

All numbers are unknown. The only known parts are
itemA, itemB, itemC, string and icon

I've tried `string.+?itemB.+?,` but it also picks up from the first occurrence of `string` rather than the one adjacent to itemB

I've also tried using `[^icon]` preceding the itemB in various positions but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[^,]+itemB[^,]+,
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex

```
 string\d+-itemB-icon\d+,
```

Answer (score 2):

The given solutions that use a restricted set of characters instead of a wildcard are simplest, but to get more at the general question: You got the non-greedy quantifier part right, but being non-greedy doesn't prevent the matcher from taking as many characters as it needs to find a match. You might be looking for the *[atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)* operator, `(?>group).` Once the group matches something, it will be treated atomically if the matcher needs to backtrack.

```
(?>string.+?item)B.+?,
```

In your example, the group matches `string331-item`, but the `B` doesn't match `R` so the whole group is tossed and the search moves to the next `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the commas separating items as a known part but use it in the example regex so I assume it can be used in a solution. Try excluding the comma as a character set instead of matching against ".".